# In Kotlin, how to record video from foreground service or from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've a foreground service running and a BroadcastReceiver in my app and I want to record a video for person who want to unlock the device. My BroadcastReceiver has the flag 'Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON ' to start the video recording. All of this must happen without opening the device nor opening my App.

How can I record a video without opening my app, just the screen of the device is on and user or person didn't unlock the device right now.

I couldn't find resources to do it on the web. Can anyone help me?